Issue in generating array in XML to JSON conversion code using XSLT
While converting XML to JSON using a generic xslt code the desired output is not getting generated as expected. Below is the example of current and desired output:
Current Output:
{
  "School": "St. Louis",
  "Class": "7th Grade",
  "Roll_number": "1234",
  "Subject": {
    "Mathematics": "A",
    "Physics": "A",
    "Chemistry": "A"
  }
} 

Desired Output:
{
    "School": "St. Louis",
    "Class": "7th Grade",
    "Roll_number": "1234",
    "Subject": [
        {
            "Mathematics": "A",
            "Physics": "A",
            "Chemistry": "A"
        }
    ]
}

My code is working when there is multiple 'Subject' items but we need an array even if there's a single occurrence.
Output with multiple Subject item:
{
    "School": "St. Louis",
    "Class": "7th Grade",
    "Roll_number": "1234",
    "Subject": [
        {
            "Mathematics": "A",
            "Physics": "A",
            "Chemistry": "A"
        },
        {
            "Mathematics": "A",
            "Physics": "A",
            "Chemistry": "A"
        }
    ]
}

We have multiple interfaces where we are using this generic XSLT code, how we can implement this without breaking the generic functionality.
Our Current Generic Code:
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:json="http://json.org/"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
  xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--
     XSLTJSON v1.0.94.

     You can use these parameters to control the output by supplying them to
     stylesheet. Consult the manual of your XSLT processor for instructions
     on how to pass parameters to a stylesheet.

     * debug           -  Enable or disable the output of the temporary
                          XML tree used to generate JSON output.
     * use-rabbitfish  -  Output basic JSON with a '@' to indicate XML
                          attributes.
     * use-badgerfish  -  Use the BadgerFish (http://badgerfish.ning.com/)
                          convention to output JSON without XML namespaces.
     * use-rayfish     -  Use the RayFish (http://onperl.org/blog/onperl/page/rayfish)
                          convention to output JSON without XML namespaces.
     * use-namespaces  -  Output XML namespaces according to the
                          BadgerFish convention.
     * skip-root       -  Skip the root XML element.
     * force-string-in -  You can either set this convert all values as strings 
                          setting the parameter to '*' or you can set a list e.g.
                          'PostalCode SubVersion' 
     * force-array-in  -  You should setup the list of node which should be converted to 
                          json array. The complete xpath of the node should be specified without 
                          any namespaces e.g.
                          '/MT_CCSN_Product_Catalog_2_01a/products,/MT_CCSN_Product_Catalog_2_01a/products/material_description'                     
     * jsonp           -  Enable JSONP; the JSON output will be prepended with
                          the value of the jsonp parameter and wrapped in parentheses.
  -->
  
  <!-- all parameter have to be set via valLookup node set -->  
 
    <xsl:param name="header"/>    
    <xsl:param name="valueLookup"/>   
    <xsl:variable name="EnvHeader" select="parse-xml($header)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="xLU" select="if ($valueLookup!='') then parse-xml($valueLookup) else()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="cs" select="$xLU/*/dataKeys/dataKey[@name='GenericXMLtoJSON_xsl']"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="debug" as="xs:boolean" select="if ($cs/row[@src='debug' and @tgt = '1']) then true() else false()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="use-rabbitfish" as="xs:boolean" select="if ($cs/row[@src='use-rabbitfish' and @tgt = '1']) then true() else false()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="use-badgerfish" as="xs:boolean" select="if ($cs/row[@src='use-badgerfish' and @tgt = '1']) then true() else false()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="use-namespaces" as="xs:boolean" select="if ($cs/row[@src='use-namespaces' and @tgt = '1']) then true() else false()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="use-rayfish" as="xs:boolean" select="if ($cs/row[@src='use-rayfish' and @tgt = '1']) then true() else false()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="jsonp" as="xs:string" select="if ($cs/row[@src='jsonp' and @tgt != '']) then $cs/row[@src='jsonp']/xs:string(@tgt) else ''"/>
    <xsl:variable name="skip-root" as="xs:boolean" select="if ($cs/row[@src='skip-root' and @tgt = '1']) then true() else false()"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="force-array-in" select="if ($cs/row[@src='force-array-in' and @tgt != '']) then $cs/row[@src='force-array-in']/xs:string(@tgt) else ''"/>
    <xsl:variable name="force-array" select="if ($force-array-in !='*') then tokenize($force-array-in,',') else $force-array-in"/>
  
    
    <xsl:variable name="force-string" select="if ($force-string-in !='*') then tokenize($force-string-in,',') else $force-string-in"/>
    <xsl:variable name="force-string-in" as="xs:string" select="if ($cs/row[@src='force-string-in' and @tgt != '']) then $cs/row[@src='force-string-in']/xs:string(@tgt) else ''"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/*">
     <!-- <xsl:element name="jroot">-->
        <xsl:value-of select="json:generate(.)"/>
      <!--</xsl:element>-->
  </xsl:template>
    
    <!--
    If you import or include the stylesheet in your own stylesheet you
    can use this function to transform any XML node to JSON.
  -->
  <xsl:function name="json:generate" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="node()"/>

    <xsl:variable name="json-tree">
      <json:object>
        <xsl:copy-of select="if (not($use-rayfish)) then json:create-node($input, false()) else json:create-simple-node($input)"/>
      </json:object>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="json-mtree">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$skip-root">
          <xsl:copy-of select="$json-tree/json:object/json:member/json:value/child::node()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$json-tree"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="output">
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="normalize-space($jsonp)">
              <xsl:value-of select="$jsonp"/><xsl:text>(</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="$json-mtree" mode="json"/><xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text/><xsl:apply-templates select="$json-mtree" mode="json"/><xsl:text/>
          
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
      
    <xsl:sequence select="$output"/>
      
  </xsl:function>
  <!--
    All methods below are private methods and should not be used
    standalone.
  -->
  <xsl:template name="json:build-tree">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="node()"/>
    <json:object>
      <xsl:copy-of select="if (not($use-rayfish)) then json:create-node($input, false()) else json:create-simple-node($input/child::node())"/>
    </json:object>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="json:create-simple-node-member" as="node()">
    <xsl:param name="type" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <json:member>
      <json:name><xsl:value-of select="$type"/></json:name>
      <json:value><xsl:copy-of select="$value"/></json:value>
    </json:member>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="json:create-simple-node" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>

    <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-simple-node-member('#name', $node/local-name())"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-simple-node-member('#text', $node/child::text())"/>

    <xsl:variable name="empty-array">
      <json:array/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="children">
      <json:array>
        <xsl:for-each select="$node/@*">
          <json:array-value>
            <json:value>
              <json:object>
                <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-simple-node-member('#name', concat('@',./local-name()))"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-simple-node-member('#text', string(.))"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-simple-node-member('#children', $empty-array)"/>
              </json:object>
            </json:value>
          </json:array-value>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="$node/child::element()">
          <json:array-value>
            <json:value>
              <json:object>
                <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-simple-node(.)"/>
              </json:object>
            </json:value>
          </json:array-value>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </json:array>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-simple-node-member('#children', $children)"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="json:create-node" as="node()">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:param name="in-array" as="xs:boolean"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$in-array">
        <json:array-value>
          <json:value>
            <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-children($node)"/>
          </json:value>
        </json:array-value>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <json:member>
          <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-string($node)"/>
          <json:value>
            <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-children($node)"/>
          </json:value>
        </json:member>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="json:create-children">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="exists($node/child::text()) and count($node/child::node()) eq 1">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="(count($node/namespace::*) gt 0 and $use-namespaces) or count($node/@*[not(../@json:force-array) or count(.|../@json:force-array)=2]) gt 0">
            <json:object>
              <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-namespaces($node)"/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-attributes($node)"/>
              <json:member>
                <json:name>$</json:name>
                <json:value><xsl:value-of select="$node"/></json:value>
              </json:member>
            </json:object>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-text-value($node)"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="exists($node/child::text())">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="(count($node/namespace::*) gt 0 and $use-namespaces) or count($node/@*[not(../@json:force-array) or count(.|../@json:force-array)=2]) gt 0">
            <json:object>
              <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-namespaces($node)"/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-attributes($node)"/>
              <json:member>
                <json:name>$</json:name>
                <json:value>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-mixed-array($node)"/>
                </json:value>
              </json:member>
            </json:object>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-mixed-array($node)"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="exists($node/child::node()) or ((count($node/namespace::*) gt 0 and $use-namespaces) or count($node/@*[not(../@json:force-array) or count(.|../@json:force-array)=2]) gt 0)">
        <json:object>
          <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-namespaces($node)"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-attributes($node)"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="$node/child::node()" group-adjacent="local-name()">
            <xsl:variable name="completeXpath" select="json:xpath(current-group()[1])"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(current-group()) eq 1 and (not(exists(./@json:force-array)) or ./@json:force-array eq 'false') and not(index-of($force-array, $completeXpath))">
                <!-- first call which say this is not string-->
                <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-node(current-group()[1], false())"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <json:member>
                  <json:name><xsl:value-of select="if($use-namespaces) then current-group()[1]/name() else current-group()[1]/local-name()"/></json:name>
                  <json:value>
                    <json:array>
                      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <!-- second call which say this is not string, need to force it down this path-->                        
                        <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-node(.,true())"/>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </json:array>
                  </json:value>
                </json:member>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </json:object>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="json:create-mixed-array" as="node()">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
    <json:array>
      <xsl:for-each select="$node/child::node()">
        <json:array-value>
          <json:value>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="self::text()">
                <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-text-value(.)"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <json:object>
                  <!-- third call which say this is not string-->                  
                  <xsl:copy-of select="json:create-node(.,false())"/>
                </json:object>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </json:value>
        </json:array-value>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </json:array>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="json:create-text-value" as="node()">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$use-badgerfish">
        <json:object>
          <json:member>
            <json:name>$</json:name>
            <json:value>
              <xsl:value-of select="$node"/>
            </json:value>
          </json:member>
        </json:object>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$node"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="json:create-string" as="node()">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$use-namespaces">
        <json:name><xsl:value-of select="$node/name()"/></json:name>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <json:name><xsl:value-of select="$node/local-name()"/></json:name>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="json:create-attributes" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$node/@*[not(../@json:force-array) or count(.|../@json:force-array)=2]">
      <json:member>
        <json:name><xsl:if test="$use-badgerfish or $use-rabbitfish">@</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="if($use-namespaces) then name() else local-name()"/></json:name>
        <json:value><xsl:value-of select="."/></json:value>
      </json:member>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="json:create-namespaces" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:if test="$use-namespaces">
      <xsl:if test="count($node/namespace::*) gt 0">
        <json:member>
          <json:name><xsl:if test="$use-badgerfish or $use-rabbitfish">@</xsl:if>xmlns</json:name>
          <json:value>
            <json:object>
              <xsl:for-each select="$node/namespace::*">
                <json:member>
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="local-name(.) eq ''">
                      <json:name>$</json:name>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <json:name><xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/></json:name>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                  <json:value><xsl:value-of select="."/></json:value>
                </json:member>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </json:object>
          </json:value>
        </json:member>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:function>


  <xsl:function name="json:xpath" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="node()" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- If the node is the root -->
      <xsl:when test="not($node/parent::node())">
        <xsl:if  test="contains(name($node),':')"> <xsl:sequence select="concat('', substring-after(name($node),':'))" /></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if  test="not(contains(name($node),':'))"> <xsl:sequence select="concat('', name($node))" /></xsl:if>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- For non-root nodes -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:if  test="contains(name($node),':')"> <xsl:sequence select="concat(json:xpath($node/parent::node()),'/', substring-after(name($node),':'))" /></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if  test="not(contains(name($node),':'))"><xsl:sequence select="concat(json:xpath($node/parent::node()), '/', name($node))" /></xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>

  <!--
    These are output functions that transform the temporary tree
    to JSON.
  -->
  <xsl:template match="json:parameter" mode="json">
    <xsl:variable name="parameters"><xsl:apply-templates mode="json"/></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="string-join($parameters/parameter, ', ')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="json:object" mode="json">
    <xsl:variable name="members"><xsl:apply-templates mode="json"/></xsl:variable>
    <parameter>
      <xsl:text/>{<xsl:text/>
        <xsl:value-of select="string-join($members/member,',')"/>
      <xsl:text/>}<xsl:text/>
    </parameter>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="json:member" mode="json">
    <xsl:text/><member><xsl:apply-templates mode="json"/></member><xsl:text/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="json:encode-string" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="string" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="replace(
          replace(
          replace(
          replace(
          replace(
          replace(
          replace(
          replace(
          replace($string,
            '\\','\\\\'),
            '/', '\\/'),
            '&quot;', '\\&quot;'),
            '&#xA;','\\n'),
            '&#xD;','\\r'),
            '&#x9;','\\t'),
            '\n','\\n'),
            '\r','\\r'),
            '\t','\\t')"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="json:name" mode="json">
    <xsl:text/>"<xsl:value-of select="json:encode-string(.)"/>":<xsl:text/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="json:value" mode="json">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="node() and not(text())">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="json"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="text()">
        <xsl:choose>
          <!--
              A value is considered a string if the following conditions are met:
               * There is whitespace/formatting around the value of the node.
               * The value is not a valid JSON number (i.e. '01', '+1', '-01', '1.', and '.5' are not valid JSON numbers.)
               * The value does not equal the any of the following strings: 'false', 'true', 'null'.
          -->
            <xsl:when test="$force-string = '*' or preceding-sibling::*/text() = $force-string">
                <xsl:text/>"<xsl:value-of select="json:encode-string(.)"/>"<xsl:text/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="normalize-space(.) ne . or not((string(.) castable as xs:integer and not(starts-with(string(.),'+') or starts-with(string(.),'-')) and not(starts-with(string(.),'0') and not(. = '0'))) or (string(.) castable as xs:decimal and not(starts-with(string(.),'+')) and not(starts-with(.,'-.')) and not(starts-with(.,'.')) and not(starts-with(.,'-0') and not(starts-with(.,'-0.'))) and not(ends-with(.,'.')) and not(starts-with(.,'0') and not(starts-with(.,'0.'))))) and not(. = 'false') and not(. = 'true') and not(. = 'null')">
            <xsl:text/>"<xsl:value-of select="json:encode-string(.)"/>"<xsl:text/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text/>null<xsl:text/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="json:array-value" mode="json">
    <xsl:text/><value><xsl:apply-templates mode="json"/></value><xsl:text/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="json:array" mode="json">
    <xsl:variable name="values">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="json"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:text/>[<xsl:text/>
      <xsl:value-of select="string-join($values/value,',')"/>
    <xsl:text/>]<xsl:text/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

The XML is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<n0:MT_Student xmlns:n0="ABC/General">
    <School>St. Louis</School> 
    <Class>7th Grade</Class> 
    <Roll_number>1234</Roll_number> 
    <Subject> 
        <Mathematics>A</Mathematics> 
        <Physics>A</Physics> 
        <Chemistry>A</Chemistry> 
    </Subject> 
</n0:MT_Student>


What language are you using? Whatever it is, there are far better options than XSLT, and the size of the script proves this. It's simply unmaintainable. XSLT has been abandoned everywhere except very old legacy applications since the 2010s. Everything is simpler and more importantly, faster, than XSLT. In C# for example, you could use JSON.NET to convert directly from XML to JSON with one line. In almost all languages you can deserialize XML to a generic object and then serialize it to JSON

As for this specific problem, there's no array of subject elements, but an element whose children you want to convert to something else. At the same time you don't want to convert MT_Student even though it's the same kind of element. You can't do both in a generic way

@PanagiotisKanavos That's a very ignorant comment. Advising people that they are using the wrong technology, when it's a technology you don't understand deeply yourself, is very poor practice. There are lots of people using XSLT (I know, because some of them buy my product) and modern versions of XSLT also provide XSLT to JSON conversion as standard. The verbosity of this code isn't because XSLT is a poor choice, it's because the OP hasn't found the right abstractions for this problem.

@PanagiotisKanavos What you have overlooked is that this XSLT code isn't just trying to convert this XML sample into the desired JSON. It's trying to convert any XML into any JSON, parameterised by some input configuration file that we haven't seen. And it's trying to tackle a particular problem in XML to JSON conversion that all the standard library functions available off the shelf handle really badly.

@MichaelKay I didn't overlook that - that's the actual problem. It's the wrong tool for the job, slower and more memory hungry than deserializing to a generic object and serializing to JSON, in any language. Some libraries can even do that in a single line, eg JSON.NET's SerializeXmlNode. The one thing that the OP wants requires a custom transformation in any language.

In fact, one way to tackle this would be to first convert the XML to the desired final form with a subjects element containing multiple subject elements and then convert it to XML.

@MichaelKay as for why I think XSLT is the wrong tool for the job .... I was one of those that thought it would be a good idea in the 2000s. And then had to fight with the XSLT-generated GUI elements in SharePoint 2007 and 2010. Generic it may be, but maintainable ... not really

The OP is clearly trying to do a better job of XML to JSON conversion than functions like JSON.NET's SerializeXmlNode do.

Either edit the code you have to add e.g.
<xsl:mode name="Subjects" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template mode="Subjects" match="/*/Subject">
  <Subjects json:force-array="true">
    <xsl:sequence select="."/>
  </Subjects>
</xsl:template>

and change the template for /* to
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="step1" as="element()">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="Subjects"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="jroot">
        <xsl:value-of select="json:generate($step1)"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

or write a new XSLT with all of the code above that xsl:imports your existing generic stylesheet.

We are trying to find a way via XSLT 3.0 means to generically take XML documents and represent them the XML as JSON just as standard convertors do e.g. XMLSpy has one and many middleware tools also do have such convertors too. Such generic convertors overcome issues like how to manage using an array even when there's no repeating child handle this by means of input rules e.g. when node "xyz" is evaluated then always consider it as an Array (even when there's no repeating child sequence) or always remove the root node or false element value to be considered as string.

Let's therefore consider these all as input arguments to the generic XSLT, which ultimately means one generic XSLT that handles lots of different XML to JSON requirements by means of input rules. That's what we wanted to achieve with the XSLT we have provided. Appreciate there are more modern ways of achieving this in XSLT 3.0 which we welcomely invite.

My main problem in answering this is that your code is doing an awful lot of things that aren't needed for this little example. All that code is clearly there for a reason, but it's not a reason I can understand from this example; you are addressing requirements that aren't evident from your question. You've said you want the solution to be "generic", i.e you want it to handle problems well beyond your specific example, but without a full description of what you want to achieve, it's hard to know what to advise.
That's evident, for example, in the fact that your program starts with a couple of parameters header and valueLookup which are clearly designed to parameterise how your stylesheet behaves, but you haven't given any information about what these parameter documents might contain.
You're using XSLT 3.0, but you don't appear to be using any of the JSON support that's present in XSLT 3.0, and it's not clear why not. You appear to be building an XML structure that mirrors the JSON maps and arrays that you want to appear in the final output, and then serializing this to JSON "by hand": why not instead construct this XML structure using the "XML representation of JSON" vocabulary defined in the XSLT 3.0 specification, which you could then output directly by calling the xml-to-json() function, and then serialising the resulting tree of maps and arrays using the JSON output method?
Having said all that, the problem stated in your question, of how to generate an array of Subject objects even when there is only one Subject, seems to be a problem of requirements specification rather than one of coding. How do you decide that the Subject should be an array when your code is completely generic and knows nothing of the data model? I've been working on a design for XML to JSON conversion for XPath 4.0, based on ideas sketched out in a Balisage paper at https://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol28/html/Kay01/BalisageVol28-Kay01.html and the thinking is that the selection of an array format here can depend on any of the following:

the user explicitly asking for a particular format to be used for particular elements
global analysis of all the input - if any of the elements with a particular name have multiple children, then treat all of them the same way
schema information, if the input document has been validated against a schema, then see what the schema allows.

Looking just at one instance is not going to give you enough information, and it's not clear how you intend to tackle that. For what it's worth, all the simple XML-to-JSON libraries that I've tried do a really bad job on this.
The current proposal for XPath 4.0, by the way, is here:
https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xpath-functions-40/Overview.html#func-elements-to-maps
but it's very much work in progress and likely to change.

What the OP asks requires a custom transformation. The problem would be a lot easier if the original XML was transformed to a more normal  form, eg wtih <subjects><subject>...</subject><subject>...</subject><subjects> before applying the generic transformation

"How do you decide that the Subject should be an array when your code is completely generic and knows nothing of the data model?" That is the crucial question here (and you could have let it go at that).

We are providing that detail in valueLookup to determine where we need array in the structure:

Below is the valueLookup in my case:








"We are providing that detail in valueLookup" - I think you need to provide a more complete description of your problem rather than adding information incrementally.

@MichaelKay, My requirement was to create an array to a specific xpath even for a single item via generic code, I have updated my code in the post which is working now and added few comments as well. I am providing the xpath in parameter value (valueLookup) to guide XSLT where I need to create the array. Below is my parameter value:








We have fixed the generic code and that's working now. We created a variable force-array similar to force string which is present in the code and in the parameter 'valueLookup' we are defining the field name where we want to create the array.

Consider to edit the your answer to add all the changes needed to the XSLT in the question.

I have created variables similar to 'force-string' & 'force-string-in' for array below are the details:
<xsl:variable name="force-array-in" as="xs:string" select="if ($cs/row[@src='force-array-in' and @tgt != '']) then $cs/row[@src='force-array-in']/xs:string(@tgt) else ''"/>
<xsl:variable name="force-array" select="if ($force-array-in !='*') then tokenize($force-array-in,',') else $force-array-in"/>
and adding the additional details via valueLookup to create the array.

My valueLookup:








Consider to edit your answer and put all the details there in a well formatted way as that way readers in the future can find the code. Code in comments is hard to read and comments might get deleted at some stage in the future so please consider to edit your answer to provide the changes there.

@MartinHonnen I have updated my post with the code which is working now and added few comments as well to make it easier to understand.
I am giving Xpath in parameter valueLookup to guide XSLT where I need to create an array. I hope that will help our community :-)
